# Negative Lookbehind not negating entire match

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

EDIT:  To be more precise the hostnames could come anywhere within a paragraph, I want to completely discard any hosts that start with https:// (or http:// actually, but just testing with https://), I don't want to capture their hostnames, but I do want to capture any hostnames that don't start with https://

I'm having trouble getting a python regex with a negative lookbehind to work.  I want to match hostnames, but not when they start with https://.

so match: caller.fls.help.test.com
**not**: https://dont-want.fls.help.test.com

My regex I've built is:

```
((?<!https:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?)(\.\w{3})?
(\.help\.test\.com|\.remote\.help\.test\.com))
```

Unfortunately, this still matches "aller.fls.help.test.com" in my example.  You can see that here:

[image]

How do I make the negative lookbehind negate the whole match?  Thanks!

Comment: do you have to use negative lookbehind? can't you use negative look ahead? ^(?!(?:https))(.*)$

Comment: Don't waste your time with regexes: use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse).

Comment: To clarify, you want to match hostnames that are just the host name, or that start with 'http://' but just not with 'https://'... is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?  I anchored the start and end of the match so that it considers the whole line from start to finish.

```
(\n|^)((?<!https:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?)(\.\w{3})?(\.help\.test\.com|\.remote\.help\.test\.com))(\n|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all hosts come in as single strings, I'd recommend another approch: Look if 'https' is contained in your string - If not, compare the hostname.

It would look like this:

```
hosts = ['caller.fls.help.test.com','https://caller.fls.help.test.com']

for host in hosts:
    if 'https' not in host:
        #Your match-regex
```